# How to prevent warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘nodes’ [-Wvla]

Tags: c++, arrays

I get this warning for these two lines of code:

```
 const int entityNumber = materialNames.size();
 SceneNode* nodes[entityNumber];
```

I thought declaring entityNumber as const would fix this. (It did in a previous version when entity number was just a value I set myself) however it doesn't appear that this works. As you can tell I am quite new to c++, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: If `materialNames.size()` can't be determined at compile-time, then the compiler can't preallocate the memory for the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably make a `std::vector`, which is a dynamic-length array, but with a lot of support for common operations:

```
// This reserves space for all the nodes you'll store
std::vector<SceneNode> nodes(materialNames.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector` instead of legacy arrays.